# Can't force gcc linker remove unuse function

Tags: eclipse, gcc, linker, static-libraries, archive

I use gcc (via eclipse) to compile c code with `.a` file staticly , But I saw that the final binary file contains function from `.a` file that I don't call them from my C code.

I don't have the source code of `.a` file , only the `.a` file itself.

Tried to remove them by add `-Wl,-gc-sections` and `-ffunction-sections` to gcc  , but still I saw many function in final binary file from `.a` file that didn't called from my c code.

Why is that?

Comment: Did you also use `-ffunction-sections`?

Comment: @ssbssa yes , `gcc  -Wl,--gc-sections -ffunction-sections -static ........`

Comment: You need to use `-ffunction-sections` when compiling the objects of the `.a` library.

Comment: @ssbssa I dont have the source code of `.a` file , I have only the `.a` file that I link to my c code . maybe I didn't understand you what to do

Comment: If you can't recompile the `.a` library with `-ffunction-sections`, then I don't think it's possible to do what you want.

Comment: @ssbssa why? it's sounds so simple , in `.a` file there are lot of function , the linker know which function do I need , so what is the problem to unlinkage the rest of functions?

Comment: The linker always adds a whole section if one symbol of it is needed.
And `-ffunction-sections` creates for each function a section, so can can be linked individually.